# Where can I find the source of the open-source Wikipedia iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, wikipedia

Where can I find the source of the open-source Wikipedia iPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the media-wiki page: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikipedia_iPhone_app.